# cython: memoryview build error with mingw

Tags: windows-7, numpy, mingw, cython, memoryview

I have been writing some python extension modules with cython. The extensions I've written build and work well. Then, I wanted to use typed memoryviews, when accessing my numpy arrays, as they seem to have several advantages http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html

However, as soon as I use a memoryview in my cython code I will get an error when building the extension. For example, if I add this test line:

cdef double[:, ::1] X = np.zeros((100, 100))

to an existing, working cython extension. I will get the following errors:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\image_box.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\image_box.def -Lc:\python27\libs -Lc:\python27\PCbuild -lp
ython27 -lmsvcr90 -o x:\ARframework\python\image_ops\image_box.pyd
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\image_box.o:image_box.c:(.text+0xe23): undefined reference to `___sync_fetch_and_add_4'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\image_box.o:image_box.c:(.text+0x3318): undefined reference to `___sync_fetch_and_add_4'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\image_box.o:image_box.c:(.text+0x4c81): undefined reference to `___sync_fetch_and_sub_4'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\image_box.o:image_box.c:(.text+0x4d37): undefined reference to `___sync_fetch_and_sub_4'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\image_box.o:image_box.c:(.text+0x10767): undefined reference to `___sync_fetch_and_sub_4'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\image_box.o:image_box.c:(.text+0x10793): undefined reference to `___sync_fetch_and_sub_4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I've tried to add -march=i486 to the gcc line, as suggested in this post:
[undefined reference to sync_fetch_and_add_4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994614/undefined-reference-to-sync-fetch-and-add-4)
but that didn't solve the problem. For that matter, I also tried -march=i586 and -march=pentium without success.

Any idea what's going on here?

My platform is Windows 7, mingw version is 4.70, Cython version is 0.17.1

Thanks

Comment: If you use new or change methods you have to adapt your. def file. This is most often overlooked. Only to test try it without `build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\image_box.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\image_box.def`.

Comment: I not sure I understand what you mean. I have deleted build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\image_box.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\image_box.def and try to build the extension again and the problem remains

Comment: Try to build with `C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\image_box.o -Lc:\python27\libs -Lc:\python27\PCbuild -lp`

Comment: Oh, we must have posted at the same time. the flag -march=i486 seems to solve the problem if applied to both compile and link steps. Just for curiosity, I have tried your line (without the .def file) and I still had the error. thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution.

Actually, the gcc flag -march=i486 does solve the problem! However, when I tested it in the console I just applied it to the gcc line for the link step (that's where I got the errors) and as it didn't solve the problem I thought it just didn't work. 
In fact, I need to use -march=i486 both in the compile and link steps, then there is no errors anymore.

As to how to include these flags when I build the extension, I have tried to add

```
import os
os.environ['LDFLAGS'] = '-march=i486'
os.environ['CFLAGS'] = '-march=i486'
```

to the setup.py  but it didn't seem to work.

So I have modified the c:\python27\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py to include these flags in the compile and link steps. Not sure if this is very elegant way of setting these flags. Any alternatives are welcome!